# Genetics problem-Height of a plant

Tags: genetics, homework

An inbred strain of plants has a mean height of 24cm. A second strain of the same species also has a mean height of 24cm. When these plants are crossed the F1 are also 24cm in height.However, when the F1 are crossed the F2 plants show a wide range of heights, the greatest number are similar to P1 and F1 but apprx. 4 out of 1000 are only 12cm tall and 4 of 1000 are 40cm tall. What fraction of the F2 plants will be apprx. 28cm in height ?

a)3/4

b)9/16

c)56/256

d)none

The answer given is c).

Comment: I know that a and b can not be the answer.

Comment: A simple google search will reveal [this website](http://www.biology-online.org/biology-forum/about28279.html) where that exact question was asked half a year ago.

Comment: Totally unrelated comment: If it is 24 cm high, I doubt it is a tree.

Comment: @skymninge done the edit !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the source that Amory cites :

> You know that the number of offspring is shown by Pascal's triangle,
>   right?
>
> For two alleles you have 1 : 2 : 1
>
> For three alleles 1 : 3 : 3 : 1
>
> For four 1 : 4 : 6 : 4 : 1 etc.
>
> So, if 4 in 1000 are 12 and 36 cm
>   tall, that means that every in 250 plants is tall like that. And on
>   which level of Pascal's triangle you have sum of 250? For two alleles:
>   1 + 2 + 1 = 4 For threee: 1 + 3 + 3 + 1 = 8 For four: 1 + 4 + 6 + 4 +
>   1 = 16 etc. until 1 : 8 : 28 : 56 : 70 : 56 : 28 : 8 : 1 Here you see
>   that you have 9 options of height. The difference is 36 cm - 12 cm =
>   24 cm. 24 cm /9 = 3 cm, so 1 plant will 12 cm, 8 plants will be 15 cm,
>   28 plants will be 18 cm, 56 plants will be 21 cm, 70 plants will be 24
>   cm (i.e. "the majority of F2 are like P1 and F1") and 56 plants will
>   be 27 cm tall out of 250 plants. Thus C is the closest.